# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str for the code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
def rate_bucket(dataset, rate_low, rate_high):
    rated_movies = dataset[(dataset['vote_average']>rate_low)&(dataset['vote_average']<=rate_high)]
    print(rated_movies)
```

> Keyword arguments:
>   vote_average -- column name for rating
>       dataset -- list containing the details of the movie
>       rate_low -- lower range of rating
>       rate_high -- higher range of rating
>         Returns rated_movies -- list of the details of the movies with required ratings
>
> Function call statement

```
rate_bucket(movies,8,10)
```

> movies is the dataset
>   8 and 10 are rating values

Comment: check ```type(dataset)```, might be its not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

> dataset -- list containing the details of the movie

You cannot extract values from a list like this:

```
dataset['vote_average']
```

This will work, only if dataset is a Panda dataframe.

Comment: Your code should work, if you pass a dataframe instead of a list.